# How to get the accurate position in the room on the smartphones GPS or blutooth or another?

Tags: android, iphone, smartphone

I would like to make an application in which:

1. There are many tables or showcases in the big room like convention center.
2. When you approach one table, one wave sound plays.
3. When you approach another table, another wave sound plays

Is it possible to make this happen on smartphones?

I guess the GPS is not accurate, I should use blutooth or something,is it correct?

Comment: based optimisation is automatically done by your cell phone, but your GPS gives u best location.

Comment: Satellite signal strength is the key. And in closed area, the chances are low.

Comment: There are a few startup companies that have had some limited successes combining GPS, accelerometer and wifi data to map indoor locations.  I haven't heard that anything marketable is out yet.

Comment: @Joe Do you knoe the name of company?,I am interested in how researches work for now.

Comment: @whitebear in-location and wifislam are the ones I remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPS is not accurate (around 10meters) which in a convention centre would not be ideal.

You can be a little more accurate with bluetooth but not much (and unless the centre is really spread out not enough I think 3-4 meters at best with no obstructions people, walls etc). Take  a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624945/how-to-measure-distance-between-two-iphone-devices-using-bluetooth) .

Have you considered creating an app that uses QR codes at each booth (fairly simple to execute and cheap).

Good luck in finding your solution.

Edit: Just a quick update but I would recommened taking a look at [iBeacons](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2013/08/ios-7-ibeacons-location-apps.html) and also [bluetooth LE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_low_energy). I hope someone finds this useful.