# Find BLE device direction

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on the project using bluetooth device. In this i have found all the necessary information and found approximate distance between two devices using signal strength. Is it possible to find the direction of a bluetooth device from my android device(for example, in my mobile application i need to show the direction of a bluetooth device like "The bluetooth device is placed in north direction").

Comment: Read this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121547/finding-the-direction-between-two-bluetooth-devices-localization)

Comment: thanks salman. Using the solution we can find the approximate distance, but the query is that i need to find the direction of the bluetooth device.

Comment: Direction implies you have a frame of reference vis-a-vis a map. If you have a map and have already assigned a point to the BLE device then you should be able to get the direction of the user from device.

Comment: @Prasanth Have you found any solution!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to find the direction by only using Android BLE information. But if you couple your application with [additional sensors such as accelerometer/gyroscope](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html) then you could potentially find out the direction by looking at the difference of distance between your bluetooth device (considering it is an Android device as you added the 'android' tag) and the bluetooth device. That would obviously require the user to move.

Comment: thanks @OlivierM. I need to know what type of sensors used to provide the direction of BLE device. Is there any way to decode the direction of android device and BLE device.

Comment: @Prasanth, the sensors are not for getting the direction. The idea OlivierM suggested is more to do with user movement and some maths around the distance.. somewhat like the game  "hot or cold"

Comment: Actually since my first answer, the BLE specification has moved on.
In Bluetooth 5.1, "Direction Finding" feature has been introduced: https://www.bluetooth.com/learn-about-bluetooth/feature-enhancements/direction-finding/
The difficulty would be to find an Android device with such support as it required a special antenna (antenna array).