# iPhones in same spot have different locations

Tags: ios, iphone, gps, location, core-location

I have an app that utilizes CoreLocation. I have it set that some position information is displayed onscreen while the app is running. I installed the app on my iPhone 6+ and my iPad 3. When I go outside holding both devices a foot apart, they claim that they are 40 feet apart. How can I fix this? My app relies on location information being uniformly correct across multiple devices, so I really need help finding a solution to this. Could it be because one is an iPad? Or that the iPad is older than the iPhone? Also, they are both running iOS 9.

Comment: GPS isn't exact and the iPad 3 doesn't even have real GPS (unless it's cellular). There is nothing you can do. You would see the same problem with a pair of dedicated Garmin GPS devices, for example.

Comment: Well I guess I'm kinda screwed... so no idea whatsoever what I could do to at least remedy the problem slightly? Is there some way to measure distance between two iPhones specifically? Through bluetooth or something?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624945/how-to-measure-distance-between-two-iphone-devices-using-bluetooth It might help you.